# Permission errors when copying files from the former internal drive of a defunct WIndows Vista laptop

Tags: windows-8, windows-vista, security, permissions, ntfs

I'm helping a friend resurrect data from the internal drive of a Windows Vista laptop which survived a house fire  -- call this SingedDrive. We bought a new Windows 8 laptop, and I've installed SingedDrive into an external case and hooked it to the Windows 8 laptop via USB. SingedDrive mounts fine and shows up on the Win8 Laptop as the D: drive.

I've set up and am running on the Win 8 Laptop as the "hidden administrator"  (net user administrator /active:yes, which completed successfully.)

However, when I attempt to copy contents of SingedDrive's Documents and Settings > My Friend >Documents to the Win 8 Laptop, I get "Folder Access Denied - You need permission to perform this action - You require permission from the computer's administrator to make changes to this folder."

I had administrator access on the old laptop as well, but all that's left of it is SingedDrive. How do I get the contents of SingdedDrive onto the Windows 8 laptop?

Comment: Sounds like you might need to take ownership of the files. You can do this by opening `Advanced` under the `Security` tab from the file properties and changing the Owner.

Answer (score 0):

I boot to a Linux live CD when transferring data. Can avoid Windows permission issues and the copy using rsync is usually faster

Answer (score 0):

Based on +Michael Frank's comment, I looked at D: drive (= SingedDrive) properties

- > Security
- > Advanced
- > Owner:
- > Change (top of window)
- > Enter the object name to select
- > Administrator
- > Check Names
- > Ok (which takes me back to the Advanced Security Settings screen, with Owner set to Administrator (top of screen)
- > check "Replace all child object permission entries ..."
- > Apply

I also had to explicitly give Administrator full control of all the files in the hierarchy, through a similar process.